# Redis pub/sub on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, publish-subscribe, sidekiq

Following the [Redis Pub/Sub](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/redis-pub-sub-how-does-it-work)

this works fine and i can publish messages in any class using

```
$redis.publish 'channel', { object: @object.id }
```

using `redis-cli > MONITOR`, I can verify that this request was published correctly

```
[0 127.0.0.1:64192] "publish" "channel" "{:object=>\"5331d541f4eec77185000003\" }"
```

the problem starts when I add a subscriber **block** to that channel in **other class (listener class)** like the following

```
class OtherClass
  $redis.subscribe('channel') do |payload|
    p payload
  end
end
```

in `redis-cli > MONITOR`, shows also that the listener is subscribed correctly

```
[0 127.0.0.1:52930] "subscribe" "channel"
```

the problem is that when i add the subscriber listener class to the same rails app... it stop working cause the `OtherClass` listens to the redis server and halt the execution of any other code... it just sit there listening.

so is there a way to make a messaging bus with redis on the same rails app... so that **events are published from some classes or service objects and there are listeners for specific channels to act upon receiving events in the background.**

i know that i might use sidekiq or any other background worker to do this job... but after a while the background workers became messy and unmaintainable.

Comment: What's the backtrace when you start the rails server without zeus?

Comment: starts and show `#<Redis::Subscription:0x007f8831620578 @callbacks={}>` and doesn't respond further... i suspect that the problem is in `OtherClass` cause i listen to redis via code block... not sure if that is correct or not.

Comment: [Pusher](http://pusher.com)

Comment: The problem is that I want to subscribe in the server not in the front end.

Comment: @rossta i updated the question making it more readable and added some extra info about the problem... any help is greatly appreciated guys

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The implementation of `Redis#subscribe` is [a loop](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/fd77358708920b3b7b76955eda22e8c89647aae5/lib/redis/subscribe.rb#L43) that will assume control of the current thread in order to listen to events. This means the boot process is halted when dropping a subscription into the context of a Rails class in the way you've shown.

You could try wrapping the call in a thread, but this approach would literally create a new subscription each time this class loaded in a new process, like a rails console or multiple unicorns. Plus, you'd have to be careful about shared state and other threading issues. This is probably not what you want.

You're best off starting a different process that loads the rails environment and subscribes to redis separately from the process(es) serving web requests. It could be a rake task like the following:

```
namespace :subscribe do
  task :redis => :environment do
    $redis.subscribe("bravo") do |on|
      on.message do |channel, message|
        Rails.logger.info("Broadcast on channel #{channel}: #{message}")
        OtherClass.some_method # yada yada
      end
    end
  end
end
```