# Rails: running a background process that doesn't end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, rake

I'm building a rails app, but I need to be able to listen for events in redis.

How might I got about starting a single separate process when the rails server starts? I only ever need one instance of it running, and it shouldn't end until the rails server stops.

I tried setting up a rake task and invoking it, and the take task starts fine, but it wouldn't let puma start. There has to be a better way. This is what I have.

lib/tasks/redis_monitor.rb

```
namespace :redis_monitor do
  task monitor: :environment do
    $redis.subscribe('channel') do |on|
      on.message do |channel, message|
        # stuff.
      end
    end
  end
end
```

config/application.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
  Rails.application.load_tasks
  Rake::Task['redis_monitor:monitor'].invoke
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644761/redis-pub-sub-on-rails

Comment: Not quite, I tried that way and I can't get both the task and webserver running consecutively. I think it might be a problem with how I'm running the task.

Comment: Re-read the question and answer again, they're nearly an exact match. You'll note that the answer suggests running the rake task as a separate process, not within your Rails server, as the subscription will be blocking for the current thread.

Comment: Too late to edit, but: Invoking the rake task within your rails initializer is running the subscription within the same thread as your webserver. You need to run the rake task as a separate process, a la `rake redis_monitor:monitor`

Comment: I see, do you happen to know in which file I'd run the command from?

Comment: @testing_josh You need to separately run the process in the same way you are running your web server.

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying it by just starting both processes separately. This works, but doesn't allow me to interact with my models from the rake task. I can't created/change objects.

Comment: I thought that is what `:environment` was doing?

Comment: @testing_josh Need to test few things in this regard. Will get back to you after that.

Comment: Hmm.. not sure what's going on. If I run `puts MyModel.all` from inside the task it makes a query. There is a module method that is called from the task, and it also works there. The module is at `lib/my_module.rb`. However, when I try to call `MyModel.create_from_message` which is a custom method on the model, I get nothing.

Comment: Can you give a paste bin url having the actual of what you are trying to do? @testing_josh

Comment: sure, here you go: https://pastebin.com/6kdLu6y2

Comment: So, according to your code, you have used `include MessageHandler` statement in your task file and even after that, you are using `MessageHandler.method_name`. Instead of this, you should directly use method_name as including a module makes all its methods available without using ModuleName which is MessageHandler in your case. 

Try to change `MessageHandler.handle(data)` to `handle(data)` and check if it works or not.

Comment: Using `handle(data)` as opposed to `MessageHandler.handle(data)` had the same effect. `Model.create_from_message` still doesn't create the record in the database. Could is have something to do with where my module is located? Does it need to be in app/lib instead of lib?